# Access denied when setting managed metadata field

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm trying to set a Managed Metadata field for a file in a Library. My code is working fine with many other site collections except for one.

When I try to set `$managedMetadataField.SetFieldValue($listitem, $term)`, I keep getting

```
Exception calling "SetFieldValue" with "2" argument(s): "Access denied.

You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."
```

Now this only happens within this one site collection. I am running the shell with the highest priveleges, I am a site collections administrator and a term store administrator as well. Between the two site collections, there is no difference in terms of priveleges.

Why could this be happening?

Comment: I suppose the obvious answer of a user locking down rights on the file is out of the question? Are you able to make these changes outside of PowerShell (like through the web gui)?

Comment: Yup. I can actually use the GUI to set the Managed Metadata field and it works just fine. I just can't seem to do it through powershell

Comment: user3519261 - Can you share the code which you are using?

Comment: @user3519261 I am having the exact same problem. Did you manage to solve it?